# JSON data table does not upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pull JSON file and then put in a data table but it is not working and I've looked up similar codes but none work.  any help?

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("file.json", function(data){
        console.log("just checking");
        var items=[];
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            console.log("double check");
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.system+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.status+"</td>");
            items.push("</tr>");
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"''>"+val.system+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"''>"+val.status+"</td>");
            items.push("</tr>");
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.system+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.status+"</td>");
            items.push("</tr>");
        });

        $('<tbody/>', {html: items.join('')}).append('table');
        console.log("triple check");
    });
```

Comment: Are you providing credentials for that url? Just tried opening it and it says you have to be logged in and response status is 403 which won't go to the success callback

Comment: yes, i have to be logged in but even when i am logged in, it only uploads the <th> but not the <td>

Comment: `$('<tbody/>', {html: items.join('')}).append('table');`, this will never work

Comment: thats exacly how they have it on youtube.  what is mission or how can i fix it?

Comment: you really should review your code rather than copy/pasting it...`items.push("<td id='"+key+"''>"+val.system+"</td>");` you are adding two single-quotes when concatenating the cell ID and that will break your HTML

Comment: items.push("<td id="+key+''>"+val.system+"</td>");                                                     is this correct now? @leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution

```js
$.getJSON("file.json", function(data){
  console.log("just checking");
  var items=[];
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
      console.log("double check");
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.system+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.status+"</td>");
      items.push("</tr>");
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"''>"+val.system+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"''>"+val.status+"</td>");
      items.push("</tr>");
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.system+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.status+"</td>");
      items.push("</tr>");
  });
  
  var joinedItems = items.join('');

  $('table').append(joinedItems);
  console.log("triple check");
});
```

Hope this will help you.